# Tabla html en django no se llena correctamente

Tags: python, django

estoy aprendiendo django (nivel básico) y al intentar renderizar un template (que contiene una tabla con 6 columnas) me sale una tabla con 7, dejándome un espacio vacío y se desordena la información. Este es el código del template, que como verán consta de 6 columnas:

```
 {%extends 'base_template/base.html' %}

    {%block head%}
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>{%block title%}Pets_list{%endblock%}</title>
    {%endblock%}



{%block content%}

<table id="pets_list_table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>name</td>
            <td>genre</td>
            <td>aprox_age</td>
            <td>rescue_date</td>
            <td>adopter</td>
            <td>applied_vaccines</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {%if pets_context%}
        {%for pet in pets_context%}
        <tr>
            <td>{{pet.name}}</td>
            <td>{{pet.genre}}/<td>
            <td>{{pet.aprox_age}}</td>
            <td>{{pet.rescue_date}}</td>
            <td>{{pet.adopter.name}} {{pet.adopter.surname}} </td>
            <td>{{pet.applied_vaccines}}</td>
        </tr>
        {%endfor%}

        {%else%}
            <h1>No hay registros de mascotas</h1>
        {%endif%}
    </tbody>
</table>

{%endblock%}
```

Este es el código de los modelos, de los cuales uso un queryset para traer los registros del modelo Pets_model:

```
    class vaccines_model(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.name)

class pets_model(models.Model):

    name             =models.CharField(max_length= 30, primary_key=True)
    genre            =models.CharField(max_length= 10)
    aprox_age        =models.IntegerField()
    rescue_date      =models.DateTimeField()
    adopter          =models.ForeignKey(adopters_model, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    applied_vaccines =models.ManyToManyField(vaccines_model, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.name)

---------------------------------------------

    from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class adopters_model(models.Model):
    name    =models.CharField(max_length= 30)
    surname =models.CharField(max_length= 30)
    age     =models.IntegerField()
    address =models.TextField()
    email   =models.EmailField(blank=True)
    phone   =models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.name)
```

---

La vista usada es una vista basada en función bastante simple, para listar registros sin omisiones:

```
def pets_list_view(request):
    pets_queryset=pets_model.objects.all()
    context={'pets_context':pets_queryset}
    return render(request, 'pets_templates/pets_list.html', context)
```

---

Y este es el resultado al probar en el navegador:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como verán, se desordena la información, dejándome una columna vacía y creando otra sin título al final (por cierto, no me aparecen los objetos del modelo applied_vaccines, pero antes debo dar solución a la columna adicional que se forma en la tabla). ¿Alguien sabe que es lo que está mal? Muchas gracias !!

Comment: Es un poco extraño que en la columna "genre" aparezca una barra `/` det´ras de male o female. Es posible que las cadenas almacenadas en la base de datos para esta columna contengan otras cosas (como tags html) que puedan estar causando el descuadre de la tabla? Prueba a hacer un `print(pets_queryset)` desde django

Comment: Hay un error tipografico en la linea `<td>{{pet.genre}}/<td>` si te fijas esta la `/` fuera en vez de estar en el `</td>`

Answer (score 2):

Hay un pequeño error al cerrar la etiqueta `</td>` como indica @Jeroni Chamorro

reemplaza la porción

```
<td>{{pet.genre}}/<td>
```

por

```
<td>{{pet.genre}}</td>
```

Código

```
{%extends 'base_template/base.html' %}

    {%block head%}
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>{%block title%}Pets_list{%endblock%}</title>
    {%endblock%}



{%block content%}

<table id="pets_list_table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>name</td>
            <td>genre</td>
            <td>aprox_age</td>
            <td>rescue_date</td>
            <td>adopter</td>
            <td>applied_vaccines</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {%if pets_context%}
        {%for pet in pets_context%}
        <tr>
            <td>{{pet.name}}</td>
            <td>{{pet.genre}}</td>
            <td>{{pet.aprox_age}}</td>
            <td>{{pet.rescue_date}}</td>
            <td>{{pet.adopter.name}} {{pet.adopter.surname}} </td>
            <td>{{pet.applied_vaccines}}</td>
        </tr>
        {%endfor%}

        {%else%}
            <h1>No hay registros de mascotas</h1>
        {%endif%}
    </tbody>
</table>

{%endblock%}
```